# Display different content depending on post author

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a different image on my page depending on who the Wordpress author of the post is.

So far I have tried a few scripts but none of them work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?> 
<?php
if ( $author('author1') ) {
    echo ' 
    <img src="">;
    '
} elseif ( $author('author2') ) {
echo '
    <img src="">;
    '
    } else {
    // if neither, echo something else
}
?>
```

Comment: `if ( $author == 'author1' )`

Comment: And a semi colon or two might not go amiss

Answer (score 0):

The [`get_the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) function return the author's display name as a string. So you have to simply compare the result of `get_the_author()`. There is no array or object as return value.

So I would go with the following solution using a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of `if`:

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?> 
<?php
    switch($author) {
        case 'author1':
            echo '<img src="">';
            break;
        case 'auhtor2':
            echo '<img src="">';
            break;
        default:
            // if neither, echo something else
    }
?>
```

In case you want to use the `if` statement you can use the following:

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?> 
<?php
    if ($author === 'author1') {
        echo '<img src="">';
    } elseif ($author === 'author2') {
        echo '<img src="">';
    } else {
        // if neither, echo something else
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! The first one worked perfectly and I can only imagine the second one too.

Thanks a lot! Really appreciated!